# Ear compiling and other projects?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, ear

If I compile my EAR projects, will all my wars and EJB will be compiled too? Or do I need to clean and build my other projects first and then compile and deploy my EAR Project?

Comment: What build tools/scripts are you using?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just got sick. I'm using Netbeans IDE 7.4